# Is a number divided by $0$ an improper fraction?

Tags: number-theory, fractions

Improper fraction is a fraction with numerator greater or equal than the denominator.

But what about $0$ denominator?

For example, are the following fractions improper?

$$ \frac{0}{0},\frac{2}{0},\frac{5}{0}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be an improper fraction, a number must be a real number.

Division by zero is undefined and does not give a real number.

Answer (score 1):

[From here](http://www.montereyinstitute.org/courses/DevelopmentalMath/COURSE_TEXT_RESOURCE/U02_L1_T2_text_final.html), an improper fraction is *always* greater than $1$ (and hence they are all *defined* fractions).

You list fractions that are *undefined*. In which case, they cannot be classified as improper.

Answer (score 1):

Improper fractions are also $\mathbf{real}$ $\mathbf{numbers}$. Division by zero yields an undefined value which is not a real number!
Thus, u cant deem a number divided by zero to be an improper fraction.